# Getting coverage with dev_appserver.py excludes my project files

Tags: google-app-engine, coverage.py

I run the following with [Coverage 3.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage), Appengine 1.8.0, Python 2.7.4 on 64 bit Ubuntu 13.04:

```
coverage run dev_appserver.py project
```

When I look at coverage results I can see details for all files **except** the ones in my project.  They show up as zero lines executed if I add `--source=project`.  Trying `--timid` made no difference. I can see others doing the exact same thing - example [1](https://github.com/daaku/ae_image/blob/master/manage#L32) [2](https://github.com/SingaporeClouds/django-gae-janrain-starter/blob/master/update-coverage-report.py#L16) - implying this used to work.

I terminate coverage/dev_appserver by sending SIGINT, and do wait for it to exit.  My suspicion is that the chicanery dev_appserver does to replicate the production environment (eg limiting modules, disabling binary modules, sort of chrooting) is breaking coverage.

Comment: Just looking at the command line, that is what I would expect.  To get coverage of your project I would imagine you need to invoke coverage as a wrapper on you handlers.  Remember the mapping from appengine to your code is via a yaml definition and I would doubt coverage could know about that.  - This is just a guess mind you ;-)  One thing to try would be to hook coverage up in appengine_config.py which is run before the sandbox. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig

Comment: coverage runs the whole python process using tracing so there is no need for additional hooking or similar shenanigans.  That leaves two possibilities - one is that sys.settrace is called to blow away coverage's tracer which doesn't seem to the case from grep, and the other is that when coverage tries to write out data at process exit it can't because appengine has hidden all the modules it needs.

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/ionelmc/python-appengine-sdk/issues/1 ?