# Code coverage for a python google-app-engine site?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unit-testing, code-coverage

I used to be able to get code coverage for unit testing a Google App Engine test via a commandline like:

```
coverage run --omit=/Applications --source=../mycode --branch /usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py ...
```

[This uses Ned Batchelder's coverage.py]  But, after recently updating to the latest SDK (after a long spell of not working on the code), I find that this does not work any more.  The server process must run the application code in a subprocess or somesuch.

I tried following this http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/subprocess.html#subprocess

I see another semi-recent question about this with a comment that suggests that coverage.py just won't work. [Getting coverage with dev_appserver.py excludes my project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785929/getting-coverage-with-dev-appserver-py-excludes-my-project-files)

I've spent a few frustrating hours googling around and trying some things with no luck.  So...is this still impossible?  Has anyone gotten code coverage to work in any manner?  Is there some other tool that can figure out code coverage?

Comment: PyCharm works well with coverage & app engine & unit testing

Answer (score 2):

A short term fix might be to run the old dev_appserver.py

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver#Running_the_Old_Development_Web_Server

Comment: Thanks for the idea--have an upvote.  This might save someone some time to know that the old server is available.  Unfortunately for me, I've made enough changes now, this might take quite a bit of work to keep both old/new server working.  I'll keep this in mind, though.

Answer (score 1):

dragonx's suggestion to use old_dev_appserver.py worked well for me. More specifically, here's what I did using App Engine 1.9.6, coverage 3.7.1, and Python 2.7 on MacOS X 10.9.3:

*MyAppDir* is the directory containing app.yaml.
*--omit* is optional. You may well not need it. I had already moved my test code out of MyAppDir because I did not want appcfg.py to upload it.
*--branch* is optional but useful.
*old_dev_appserver.py* ships (for now) with App Engine. There is no need to download or install a copy.

```
# One time:
sudo pip install coverage

# Start the server:
APP=MyAppDir
coverage run \
  --source=$APP \
  --omit='$APP/exclude/*' \
  --branch \
  /usr/local/bin/old_dev_appserver.py \
  $APP

# Run your tests in a separate tab. In my case I use this command:
webdriver/system_tests.py

# Kill the server with Control-C once the tests are finished.

# Display a quick text summary:
coverage report -m

# Generate and open an HTML report linking to line by line coverage:
coverage html
open htmlcov/index.html
```

My relatively straightforward app (email, full text search, ndb, urlfetch, webapp2) did not need any changes to work with old_dev_appserver. I did remove the flags I passed to dev_appserver. I was able to live without them. --port is supported if you need it, as are a few others.

If you'd like to see code coverage support in future versions of dev_appserver.py please vote up [Add support for code coverage tests and some documentation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63810075), formerly https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4936.